# Implementing Splash screen ASP.NET MVC + Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

We are using kendo UI for our asp.net mvc application, since we are using most of kendo UI Controls, for  the first time, it takes some 30-45 sec for loading entire screen, it is because of Kendo UI JS references and CSS, during this time, page remains empty (white background) causing less intuitive for users. Is it possible to show  splash screen during loading of JS (heavy JS loading), so that user can expects that something is loading. Is there builtin control available in kendo for UI initialization and showing splash screen,

Comment: I would be very surprised if a 30 to 45 seconds delay on a broadband connection is happening just because of loading Kendo's JS and CSS files. You can add a "loading" screen to your page, but if I were you, I would try to improve the performance of the page first. Are you **synchronously** loading a large amount of data into one of the Kendo controls? Can you share a screenshot of a network profile of the page?

Comment: 30-45 seconds is likely too long to make users wait. The splash/loading page is a bit like putting a bandage on a broken limb. Have you looked at the back-end and web admin console to determine that this is for sure because of loading js?